# Edit a file with an external application in Java and write back?

Tags: java, desktop, external-application

How do you edit a file from a Java application when you do not know which application the file is associated with. Also, because I'm using Java, I'd prefer a platform independent solution. After the external application was closed I want write the changes in the file back. The edit file was a local temp file. The real file is saved on a server, in an archive or any else.

I now I can use the class [Desktop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) to open a file for edit. But how can I detect if the file was closed.

Comment: The external application will write the file back if saved.  Your Java app doesn't need to write it back. I don't understand your question.

Comment: @jzd - I have make the question clearer (I hope). Because the content is not saved in the local file system a temp copy was created for the edit operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario where the external application is unknown and is not invoked from you java application then you can create a demon thread. I am assuming that you application knows the location of the file. This demon thread can check for any lock on the file and last updated time of the file when lock is released. If the last updated time changes you know file is changed.

Another option could be using 3rd party api like FileListener from apache which also does kind of the same thing internally.

Comment: How can I check for any lock without creating a file lock? If I create a file lock then the external application can be have problems.

Comment: You can use FileChannel.tryLock() from java.nio. Refer [FileChannel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#tryLock())

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by 'After the external application was closed I want write the changes in the file back.'

If you just want to wait for the external application to finish, you can instead use RunTime :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("mycommand");
p.waitFor()
```

Comment: Yes, I does want know if the external application is finish. But I does not know the application which is used for edit. It can be a wide range of files like images, office documents, source files, log files etc.